# Writing/reading binary file

Tags: java, file, inputstream, binaryfiles, outputstream

I have 2 classes to write and read binary file. I have to store an ArrayList of prime numbers to binary file, so that i have first 8 byte in each line of file represent how many numbers will be saved in that line(the lines are a formality, I make them with the '/n' symbol and then read that symbol without adding anything). Depending on how many bytes is needed to store a prime number i have to store them in 1 line, if it is 1 byte, second line if ot is 2 byte, and so on.(i will have maximum 3 lines with 1,2,3 bytes numbers).
Here is my code.

```
class Write2 {
    public static final int[] Byte_Sizes  = {1,2,3};
    public  void write(String filename, ArrayList<Integer> data) {

        try( OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
            int[] arr = countNumbersInEachLine(data);
            int index = 0;

            for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
                long tmp = arr[j];

                for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
                    os.write((int) (tmp >> i * 8));
                }

                while (index<data.size() && index< tmp){
                    int size = getByteSize(data.get(index));

                    for (int b = size -1; b >= 0 ; --b) {
                        os.write((int) (data.get(index) >>> b * 8));
                    }

                    index++;
                }
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static int getByteSize(int value) {
        int size =1;
        while (value >= Math.pow(2, 8*size)) {//num >= (1 << (8 * size))
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }
    public int[] countNumbersInEachLine(ArrayList<Integer> primes){
        int[] amount_in_each_line = new int[Byte_Sizes.length];
        for(int j =0; j< Byte_Sizes.length; j++) {
            int counter =0;
            for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
                if(getByteSize(primes.get(i)) == Byte_Sizes[j]){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            amount_in_each_line[j] = counter;
        }
        return amount_in_each_line;
    }
}
class Read2 {
    public  ArrayList<Integer> readFromFile(String filename) {
        ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();

        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename)) {

            while (true){
                long count =0;
                for(int i = 0; i<8; i++ ){
                    long a = is.read();

                    if(a == -1){
                        is.close();
                        return data;
                    }

                    count =( count<< 8) | a;
                }


                for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){

                    int value =0;

                    if(count == 54){
                        int a = is.read();
                        if(a == -1){
                            is.close();
                            return data;
                        }

                        value = ( value<<8) | a;
                    }
                    else if(count == 6488){
                        for(int f =0; f<2; f++){
                            int a = is.read();
                            if(a == -1){
                                is.close();
                                return data;
                            }

                            value = ( value<<8) | a;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(count == 760888){
                        for(int f =0; f<3; f++){
                            int a = is.read();
                            if(a == -1){
                                is.close();
                                return data;
                            }

                            value = ( value<<8) | a;
                        }
                    }

                    data.add(value);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Method will culculate how many 1/2/3 bytes numbers exist(it works properly and return values 54 6488 760888) Method getByteSize detect how many bytes is needed to store number.

So i have problems some unknown problems. I used debugger to check whether my numbers are read correctly, and it works okey,

```
long count =0;
                for(int i = 0; i<8; i++ ){
                    long a = is.read();

                    if(a == -1){
                        is.close();
                        return data;
                    }

                    count =( count<< 8) | a;
                }
```

using this, i read first numbers in each line, that showed how many 1 byte, 2 byte, and 3 byte numbers there would be. First it read 54, then reed 54 1-byte numbers in that line, tham 6488 and 6488 2-byte numbers and after this last number isn't read correctly. Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?